# tornado server is incompatible with threading module

Tags: multithreading, tornado

I'm using tornado with threads.

In short, each time the websocket handler receives a requests, it start to execute a task, which might take a few minutes.

However, once a client is connected, no other client can be connected, until the first one disconnects.

Any ideas?

I've attached a minimal example that uses `time.sleep` to simulate long running tasks.

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import time
import json
import threading

class TaskHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        pass

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def on_message(self, message):
        try:
            print 'received: ', message
            self.write_message(json.dumps({'status': 'running'}))

            def worker_A(kwargs):
                time.sleep(100)
                pass

            def worker_B(kwargs):
                time.sleep(100)
                pass

            threads = []
            for target in [worker_A, worker_B]:
                t = threading.Thread(target = target, args = ({'xxx': 'yyy'}, ))
                t.daemon = True
                t.start()
                threads.append(t)

            for t in threads:
                t.join()

        except Exception, e:
            print 'TaskHandler: exception: ', e
            pass

        self.write_message(json.dumps({'status': 'done'}))

    def on_close(self):
        pass

class Server(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            ('/task', TaskHandler),
        ]

        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server  = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Server())
    server.listen(8765, address = '127.0.0.1')
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor i think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You block the whole Tornado event loop for 100 seconds in `t.join`. Unless you have a `yield` statement or schedule a callback and exit a function, then your function is not asynchronous. Notice how your function "on_message" begins two threads and then calls `t.join` on each -- how can Tornado's event loop accomplish any other work while your function is waiting for `t.join`?

Instead, use a ThreadPoolExecutor something like this:

```
thread_pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(4)

class TaskHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    # Make this an asynchronous coroutine
    @gen.coroutine
    def on_message_coroutine(self, message):
        print 'received: ', message
        self.write_message(json.dumps({'status': 'running'}))

        def worker_A(kwargs):
            time.sleep(100)
            pass

        def worker_B(kwargs):
            time.sleep(100)
            pass

        futures = []
        for target in [worker_A, worker_B]:
            f = thread_pool.submit(target, {'xxx': 'yyy'})
            futures.append(future)

        # Now the event loop can do other things
        yield futures

    def on_message(self, message):
        IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.on_message_coroutine,
                                        message)
```